# Server-side generated client-side Javascript sandbox

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, server-side-rendering, sandbox, serverside-javascript

I currently have a sandbox that runs client-side using the `with` + `proxy` technique, but I want to move all the templating to server-side rendering, both to relieve pressure on the clients' machines as to be able to make my CSP more strict.

However I can't just move over my "sandboxed code generator" to the server and call it a day, as *all* my server-side code is in strict mode, ergo no `with`, ergo no sandbox.

Is there any way for me to make sure that code in templates only do what they should do? Without writing a custom parser, absolutely not going to do that.

Comment: `Function("with({key: 'value'}) console.log(key);")()` is a way, because `Function` opts out the *use strict* directive by specs.

Comment: I cant use this as I want to explicitly remove eval from the client (and Function constructor is eval)

Comment: 1. `Function` is **not** `eval` ... they do different things. 2. `Function` is what you can execute in the server, as you asked how to execute code in the server.

Comment: alternatively, you can create a vm https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Comment: ok correct, it is not eval, but it does nearly the same, and If I enable `unsafe-eval` in my CSP Function also doesn't work anymore as the runtime-js-parsing is disabled. Thats what I meant. and I cant run function on the server either, I want to extract the js from the templates, safe them as a callable piece of code in a file, this generated file will be included on my client. It is server-side rendering, the app runs client side. I do want templating, but don't want aval-ing.

Comment: Look, I have simply commented on *your* post, precisely this part: "*I can't just move over my "sandboxed code generator" to the server and call it a day, as all my server-side code is in strict mode, ergo no with, ergo no sandbox*". Yes, you can move that in your server because `Function` enables `with` statement *in the server too*. That was my comment.